# Installing windows 7 on Imac

Tags: bootcamp, startup, windows, optical-drive

I have a mid-2010 27" iMac with macOS 10.12.5 and an external DVD - USB SuperDrive (the internal DVD drive is broken).

I can't install Windows 7 from DVD with Bootcamp. After downloading support software to USB flash drive via BootCamp Assistant, I get an error on restart:

> No bootable device -- Insert boot disk and press any key.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to an ISO. 
[Apple's official guide](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203909)

Answer (score -1):

After days and days of searches and failed attempts I managed to install windows7 with the technique described by this boy:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pSFUMdzWaA&ab_channel=YassineIBNELHASSAN

Comment: First of all, welcome to Ask Different! :) Secondly, thank you for sharing the solution you found to your question. This makes the site very useful for many users! However, can I suggest you also add to your answer a summary of what you did? This will help users in case the YouTube video you link to is removed in future.